# I am having trouble getting my head around this statement:

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am having trouble getting my head around this statement:

```
while (a && b) {
a > b ? a %= b : b %= a;
}
```

What is it doing exactly? Can it be converted to an if statement?

Comment: Where did you come across that statement?

Comment: plain english: while a and b are both approximately equivalent, if a > b, a = a mod b, otherwise b = b mod a.

Comment: Thank you chiliNUT. Plain English works for me! Hey Kevin, I think I got this snippet from this site as part of a solution to calculate the sum of the lowest common multiples.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this up into parts:

```
while (a && b) {

}
```

this means while `a` and `b` are "truthy" values (in this case, not `0`) then the loop will continue:

```
a > b ? a %= b : b %= a;
```

this is a ternary operator: `x ? y : z`

if `x` evaluates to true, execute `y`. if `x` evaluates to false, execute `z`.

Thus, in this case if `a > b` is true,

`a %= b` will run. `a %= b` is shorthand for `a = a % b`.

if `a > b` is false,

`b %= a` will run. again, `b %= a` is shorthand for `b = b % a`.

Thus, the loop will keep running until either `a` or `b` is equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you eddyjs. This shorthand had me scratching my head and maybe I was just too tired to understand the "official" language of mozilla.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is calculating the highest common factor of `a` and `b` using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).

It's using the ternary operator in place of an if-statement, and other unreadable cuteness.

`a ? b : c` is an expression that evaluates to `b` if `a` is truthy, otherwise `c`. Note that it is an expression with a value and it's bad form to use it purely for side effects or for complicated calculations where an if-statement would be clearer.

The `a && b` in the while-condition ensures that the loop will stop once either `a` or `b` is zero.

And `a %= b` is equivalent to `a = a % b`, where `%` is the remainder operator.

It might be worthwhile reading [MDN's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) if this syntax is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: This is the answer that actually goes further then explaining the code. It explains the function of the code. Nice work.

Comment: Thank you, King Mob, for an explanation that I can grasp. It's not my code - I was just trying to understand it. And thanks for the link to the guide which I will study - studiously!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily expand the if like so:

```
while (a && b) {
  if (a > b) {
    a %= b;
  } else {
    b %= a;
  }
}
```

%= means take the mod of the left with the right, and assign the result to the left.

Comment: That's the sort of explanation I can understand - thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ternary operator and is used as follows:

condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false

( a > b  )? ( a %= b )    : ( b %= a )

```
while (a && b) {
    if ( a > b ) {
        a %= b 
    }else{
        b %= a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vnponce. It always seems to be late when I look at this sort of thing and your explanation clears the waters for me.